# Копия объекта List<T> по значению

Tags: c#

Есть класс продуктов:

**Product.cs**

```
public class Product
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Я знаю что классы это *ссылочный* тип и согласно этому инициализоровал новый `List<T>` вот так:

**Program.cs**

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
products.Add(new Product { Number = 1 });
products.Add(new Product { Number = 2 });

List<Product> currentProducts = new List<Product>(products);
currentProducts.RemoveAll(x => x.Number == 2);
currentProducts[0].Number = 22;
```

Строка `currentProducts[0].Number = 22` все равно изменяет `products[0].Number`. **А мне необходимо, чтобы так не происходило. Как этого добиться?**

Но вот `currentProducts.RemoveAll(x => x.Number == 2)` не затрагивает `products` - количество объектов `Product` в `products` остается прежним. Это еще больше меня запутало.

Т.к. хочется побольше знать, что происходит "подкапотом", хотелось бы чтобы предлагаемое решение было с описанием.

Comment: `new List<Product>(products)` копирует лист, но не продукты. То есть в результате вы имеете новый лист, со ссылками на те же самые продукты.

Comment: [под капотом](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,74)

Comment: почему бы в этом случае не использовать структуры вместо классов?

Comment: Непонятно, _для чего_ вам такое поведение. Если вы объясните, почему вам нужно, чтобы `currentProducts[0].Number = 22;` не изменяло значение `currentProducts[0].Number`, возможно, можно будет предложить идею получше.

Comment: @VladD `некоторые` поля объектов списка `products` инициализируются значениями загруженные из `xlsx.файла` и они `постоянные`. А остальные значения (для `меняющихся` полей) подгружаются из базы.

Comment: таки сделать эти поля свойствами и на сеттер игнорировать ввод. Хотя это путь к трудно уловимым ошибкам

Comment: @adamshakhabov: Если это постоянные поля, зачем вы даёте на них сеттер? Уберите сеттер, оставьте лишь геттер.

Comment: @VladD но им назначаются значения. Просто назначаются только `один раз`. Или можно сделать как-то, чтобы значение можно было присвоить только один раз?

Comment: @adamshakhabov: В конструкторе? Да.

Comment: @VladD `.Add(new Product {Number = 1})` - это по моему через конструктор считается, так?

Comment: @adamshakhabov: Нет :( Через конструктор — это `.Add(new Product(1))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цитата из MSDN

> Существует множество способов реализации операции глубокого копирования, если
>   выполняемая операция неполной копии MemberwiseClone не
>   соответствует вашим потребностям. , включая следующие основные
>   параметры:
>
> - Вызовите конструктор класса объекта для копирования для
>     создания второго объекта значениями свойств, которые берутся из
>     первого объекта. Это предполагает, что значения объекта полностью
>     определяется его конструктором.
> - Вызов MemberwiseClone метод для создания
>     неполной копии объекта, а затем создать новые объекты значения которых являются ссылочными
> - Сериализовать объект для
>     получения его глубокой копии, а затем восстановить сериализованные
>     данные в другую объектную переменную.
> - Используйте отражение с рекурсии
>     для создания глубокой копии.

**Вариант реализации интерфейса `ICloneable<T>`**

```
    public class Product : ICloneable<Product>
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }

        public Product Clone()
        {
            //return this.MemberwiseClone();
            return new Product() { Number = this.Number };
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
        products.Add(new Product { Number = 1 });
        products.Add(new Product { Number = 2 });

        List<Product> currentProducts = products.Select(p => p.Clone()).ToList(); 

        currentProducts.RemoveAll(x => x.Number == 2);
        currentProducts[0].Number = 22;

        Console.WriteLine(products[0].Number);
    }
```

**Вариант Сериализация**

[Ссылка на Ideon](http://ideone.com/9yw6pz)

Из недостатков : все сериализируемые классы приедтя пометить как [Serializable]

```
        [Serializable]
        public class IdInfo
        {
            public int IdNumber { get; set; }

            public IdInfo(int IdNumber)
            {
                this.IdNumber = IdNumber;
            }
        }

        [Serializable]
        public class Product 
        {
            public int Number { get; set; }
            public IdInfo IdInfo { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public Product DeepCopy()
            {
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

                formatter.Serialize(stream, this);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                var product = (Product)formatter.Deserialize(stream);

                stream.Close();
                stream.Dispose();

                return product;

            }
        }
```

ну и где-то в main...

```
   List<Product> currentProducts = products.Select(p => p.DeepCopy()).ToList();
```

Comment: это если всего одно поле в классе :)

Comment: @Grundy, ну так в примере всего одно и есть :) Сейчас погуглю как оптимизировать это

Comment: никак - либо руками все прописывать, либо через рефлексию

Comment: Да - действительно у меня в `Product` несколько полей. Одно из полей тоже `класс`. Тогда думаю для него тоже надо реализовать интерфейс `ICloneable`. Так?

Comment: @adamshakhabov, да для всех ссылочных объектов нужно тоже реализовать  ICloneable<T>, остальные поля можно скопировать через  this.MemberwiseClone();